# Rendering of Bootstrap Glyphicon set not working in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

The normal "wrench" icon and carat should display here, but instead I am getting this (notice the weird rectangle and underscore):

[image]

Also, the "sort" icon should show, but I am getting this (which looks like another icon was used on top of the one I wanted):

[image]

This does not always happen in Firefox and does not appear to ever happen in Chrome. Does anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: Could you please post your code at jsfiddle.net or similar?

Comment: Bug in Firefox's font rendering? Corrupted font files?